# org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<com.test.entity.VendorEntity@3e60be48> but was:<null>

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, spring-boot-test

I am running Junit test case for service layer but I am getting

> org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:VendorEntity@3e60be48 but was:null

When vendorRepo.save(vendorEntity) method is called it returns null, I am not able to figure out why it is returning null. Below is my code.

```
@Autowired
private VendorSvc vendorSvc;

@MockBean
private VendorRepo vendorRepo;

@Test
public void testSaveVendorForm() {
     VendorEntity vendorEntiy = getVendor();
     Mockito.when(vendorRepo.save(vendorEntiy)).thenReturn(vendorEntiy);
     // saveVendorForm return null 
     VendorEntity vendorEntity2 = vendorSvc.saveVendorForm(getVendorDto());
     assertThat(vendorEntity2).isEqualTo(vendorEntiy);
}
```

> After making some change in saveVendorForm which accept vendorEntity below code works but I don't want to pass entity class object to service layer as I want to create entity object in service layer and pass it to dao layer

```
@Test
public void testSaveVendorForm() {
    VendorEntity vendorEntity = getVendor();
    Mockito.when(vendorRepo.save(vendorEntity)).thenReturn(vendorEntity);
    VendorEntity vendorEntity2 = vendorSvc.saveVendorForm(vendorEntity);
    assertThat(vendorEntity2).isEqualTo(vendorEntity);
}

private VendorEntity getVendor() {

    VendorEntity vendorEntity = new VendorEntity();

    SocietyEntity societyEntity = new SocietyEntity();
    societyEntity.setSocietyId(1L);

    PincodeEntity pincodeEntity = new PincodeEntity();
    pincodeEntity.setPincodeId(1L);

    vendorEntity.setVendor("XYZ Cafe");
    vendorEntity.setAddress("abc address");
    vendorEntity.setEmailId("xyz@gmail.com");
    vendorEntity.setContactNo1("123456");
    vendorEntity.setContactNo2("123457");
    vendorEntity.setSocietyId(societyEntity.getSocietyId());
    vendorEntity.setPincodeId(pincodeEntity.getPincodeId());
    vendorEntity.setWebsite("www.xyzabc.com");
    vendorEntity.setCategoryId(2);
    vendorEntity.setStatus(Constant.ACTIVE);
    vendorEntity.setCreatedBy(1L);
    vendorEntity.setCreatedDate(CommonUtil.getCurrentTimeStamp());
    vendorEntity.setCreatedIp(Constant.DEFAULT_IP);
    vendorEntity.setSocietyEntity(new SocietyEntity());
    vendorEntity.setPincodeEntity(new PincodeEntity());
    return vendorEntity;
}

@Override
public VendorEntity saveVendorForm(VendorDto vendorDto) {

    VendorEntity vendorEntity = new VendorEntity();

    // copy properties from (source,target)
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(vendorDto,vendorEntity);

    vendorEntity.setCreatedBy(vendorDto.getCreatedBy());
    vendorEntity.setCreatedDate(vendorDto.getCreatedDate());
    vendorEntity.setCreatedIp(vendorDto.getCreatedIp());

    vendorEntity.setModifiedBy(vendorDto.getModifiedBy());
    vendorEntity.setModifiedDate(vendorDto.getModifiedDate());
    vendorEntity.setModifiedIp(vendorDto.getModifiedIp());

    vendorEntity.setSocietyEntity(new SocietyEntity());
    vendorEntity.setPincodeEntity(new PincodeEntity());

    vendorEntity.setStatus(Constant.ACTIVE);
    // below code returns null but works well when run in tomcat and form submitted through web browser
    return vendorRepo.save(vendorEntity); 
}

public interface VendorRepo extends JpaRepository<VendorEntity, Long> {
}
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong in the code.

Comment: How vendorRepo is declared in your test class ? Can you attach the Complete test class ?

Comment: @bittu I have added code for vendorRepo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mocking save method for object vendorEntity but actaully passing a different object created via VendorDto object. Both are different object I guess which causing null in return.

Follow my comment on your test case(did not make any change except comments).

```
@Test
public void testSaveVendorForm() {
     VendorEntity vendorEntiy = getVendor();
     //Mocking the verndorRepo.save to return vendorEntiy when save is called with vendorEntiy
     Mockito.when(vendorRepo.save(vendorEntiy)).thenReturn(vendorEntiy);
     // saveVendorForm return null 
     // Actually passed a different object which may not be equal to vendorEntiy
     VendorEntity vendorEntity2 = vendorSvc.saveVendorForm(getVendorDto());
     assertThat(vendorEntity2).isEqualTo(vendorEntiy);
}
```

`saveVendorForm` may not be generating the exact VendorEntity object that we configured in mocking.

So if you make sure that `getVendorDto()` to VendorEntity trasnformation generates object similar to vendorEntity(the one which is getting created via getVendor method) then your test case would work as expected.

Similar objects means `equals` method should return `true` for given objects.

Comment: will valid and post the result

Comment: Yup let me know if any issues.

Comment: I found that since 2 different VendorEntity object is passed even though both have same value saveVendorForm return null. If I make a change in saveVendorForm(vedorEntity) which accept vendorEntity instead of vendorDto and pass the same vendorEntity then junit runs successfull. I have added code with is working

Comment: I doubt something is wrong between conversion from DTO to VendorEntity and Does VendorEntity/SocietyEntity/PincodeEntity has equals method implemented ? as we are creating the new object for SocietyEntity/PincodeEntity while doing the conversion.

Comment: It finally worked after implement equals and hashcode Using the entity identifier and the test passed successfully

Comment: Right. This is what I was expecting. Good that finally you got it sorted